# Prestashop 1.7 Hook actionCustomerAccountAdd not fired

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am trying to add a hook in my custom module but it is not fired after I add a customer both in prestashop backoffice or by using the webservice.

The hook name I am trying to register is "actionCustomerAccountAdd".

This is the relevant code of the module. Please could you help me? I am a PHP developer but it is the first time I develop in Prestashop side.

```
/**
     * Don't forget to create update methods if needed:
     * http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Enabling+the+Auto-Update
     */
    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install()
            && $this->createRequiredDBTables()
            && $this->registerHook('actionCustomerAccountAdd');
    }
```

I have this code to check in logs files or page but it is not fired:

```
public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd($params)
    {
        $this->logger->info('Hook action customer account add fired');
        echo 'hook fired';
        die();
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that hook `actionCustomerAccountAdd` is fired only on front-office, you will need to use `actionObjectCustomerAddAfter`, dynamic hook executed in `classes/ObjectModel.php`

Comment: Thank you @Krystian Podemski. It works great changing the hook and resetting the module to re-register the new hook!